# Wrong part of the if statement is executing

Tags: php

```
$STH = $DBH -> prepare( "select * from table where id = :id" );
$STH -> bindParam( ':id', $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 4 );
$STH -> execute();
$result = $STH -> fetch();

if( isset( $result["id"] ) ) {
    // do this if records are returned
} else {
    // do this if no records are returned
}
```

For some reason, the first part of the `if` statement executes even if no records are returned, why is that happening?  I'm assuming it's because of the `isset`, but don't know what to change that too?

Comment: How do you figure that no records are returned?!

Comment: Put `var_dump($result)` inside first part of your `if` block and find your answer

Comment: Why not just use `$STH->rowCount() > 0` ?

Comment: try to use: fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: Does if (!empty($result["id"]) work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing like this

```
  if ($STH->rowCount() > 0) {

  } else {

  }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be to use this as a condition:

```
if($STH->rowCount()>0){
    // do this if records are returned
} else {
    // do this if no records are returned
}
```